# Create Shared Variables in Memory For Child Process to Parent C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process

I'm programming a local streaming service. And I need to use two different Process for Server Software (Do not ask why e.e). The **"child"** Process Makes The Hardwork and I need to get results, but the workflow are in milliseconds ('cause is a videogames stream service). I tried with: `Process.OutputDataReceived` EventHandler, but the results are a lot of text and the *Console* takes valious time to write.

Also I tried with **FileStream**, But by logic and research I knew that using `MemoryStream` is faster to store and obtain data. The problem is that I do not know how to obtain the data that the **child** process saves.

**The next code is not bad, but it's just to let them know that I also try with that code:**

*Parent Process:*

```
public class MemoryRead
{
    Process process = null;
    int bufferSize = 256000;

    public MemoryRead(Process Process, int BufferSize){
        process = Process;
        bufferSize = BufferSize;
    }

    const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
      int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    public string GetString(int BytesAdress = 0x0046A3B8)
    {
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, BytesAdress, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    }

}
```

*Child Process:*

```
GCHandle handler = GCHandle.Alloc(VideoData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr address = handler.AddrOfPinnedObject();
Console.WriteLine((address.ToString()));
```

The Child Process returns a int "address", and I Get that with `Process.OutputDataReceived` EventHandler to Call `MemoryRead.GetString()`, but that returns null, Basically as if the address did not exist. I just want more options, also if they have nothing to do with `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Look up "memory mapped file".  You might also want to look up "named pipes"

Comment: Well I searching for "Memory Mapped File" and for "named pipes", but When I tried to implement that in my proyect a error appears, Basically Unity3D don't have access to `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` and `System.IO.Pipes` Classes. Well,I think a need to put togheter in one Process.

Comment: You might want to tag your question with `unity` then